# Does anyone know how to add new user on rocket universe?

Tags: jdbc, universe, rocket

I have installed Rocket Universe database on my computer, however, I need a username and password to connect through JDBC. Do you know how I can add a new user?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You local user account should get you access as long as it has access to the Universe database directory. Universe uses the OS's access control to restrict/allow access to the database. Therefore, any new user added to your OS will also be a database user if their account has access to the Universe database directory.